# xprintidle error, "screen saver extension not supported"

Tags: virtualbox, 21.04

I'm trying to use xprintidle for a python script but it always crashes when it tries to get the idle time.

Typing xprintidle into the terminal returns "screen saver extension not supported".

Running Ubuntu 21.04 in VirtualBox 6.1.26

Im fairly new to linux so I'm lost on how to fix this.

Anyone able to help?